# What was Cameron Bancroft trying to do with the tape?

Tags: cricket

In the recent Test match pitting Australia against South Africa (3rd Test of the 2017-18 Sunfoil Test Series), Cameron Bancroft of Australia was caught using yellow tape to alter the condition of the ball. What effect was he going for though? Why use tape?

Answer (score 1):

Actually it was not tape.. The yellow object was "SandPaper", which is used to make one side rough.

> In what is an extensive and revealing statement, Warner appears to
>   have been the brains behind the decision to go into the third day of
>   the third Test with a plan to cheat by altering the surface of the
>   ball with “sandpaper” – not sticky tape covered in dirt as Bancroft
>   first alluded to in a press conference – which Bancroft then carried
>   out only to be caught by television cameras. - News Report

[independent.co.uk](https://www.independent.co.uk/sport/cricket/steve-smith-banned-david-warner-cameron-bancroft-cheating-ball-tampering-video-australia-a8277586.html), [cricket.com.au](https://www.cricket.com.au/news/sandpaper-not-sticky-tape-revelation-australia-media-statement-ball-tampering-cameron-bancroft/2018-03-28), [independent.co.uk](https://www.independent.co.uk/sport/cricket/cameron-bancroft-ball-tampering-video-lied-sandpaper-sticky-tape-australia-cheating-a8278986.html)

Answer (score 0):

The aim, as admitted by Bancroft, was to rough up one side of the ball [in order to get it to reverse swing](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/17573/what-is-the-science-behind-reverse-swing). Bancroft himself said ([as quoted by Cricinfo](http://www.espncricinfo.com/story/_/id/22897995/desperation-drove-australia-cheat-steven-smith)):

> I saw an opportunity to use some tape, get some granules from rough patches on the wicket to change the ball condition